# The method window() is undefined for the type Object

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting an error saying "The method window() is undefined for the type Object" and not sure why. This is what my code looks like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Maximize2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to close and reopen your IDE

Comment: I just did and I am still not seeing it resolved. It seems that "window" is not identified as an object. Is there a way I can make it an object? @Guy

Comment: You probably need to update Firefox to the latest, redownload and reinstall all the Selenium jars. Something is wrong with your install or you have some mismatch.

Comment: OK so I installed the Jar files from this site: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/. I clicked download for Java 3.0.1. When I downloaded only 1 zip called "selenium-java-3.0.1.zip" was downloaded. I unzipped it and a directory was created called "selenium-java-3.0.1". NOW, when I open that folder, only 4 things appear....1). client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar; 2). "lib" folder which has a bunch of jar files; 3) LICENSE; and 4). NOTICE....... Is this all correct? @JeffC

Comment: You would be better served by googling an installation guide for the step-by-step process.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet above works for me with Selenium 2.53.1, Firefox 51.0.1 and Fedora 25.

Try to update your Selenium and browser and run the test again.

Comment: I just installed Selenium a few days ago so it should've downloaded the latest release. Are you using the Eclipse compiler? @Janux

Comment: No, I tried it out with IntelliJ by checking out a company repository where all the dependencies are installed configured correctly. Your IDE should not be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the setup for Eclipse like this:

- Download and unzip Selenium Client Driver for Java
  http://seleniumhq.org/download/#client-drivers
- Create a new project
- Right click on project in Package Explorer
- Click “Properties”, then “Java Build Path”
- Click “Add External JARs” and select all jar files from “libs” folder and "selenium-java-$VERSION.jar"
- Run the snippet again

You should also consider using Gradle for your dependency management. This tutorial and googling for "gradle selenium" should help: https://gradle.org/uncategorized/video-tutorial-test-automation-selenium-web-application/